# Seemingly unprovoked software corruption on external drive. Can I salvage?

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, data-recovery, fsck-hfs

I have an external disk on my Mojave system that seemingly had the volume name overwritten with another volume's name and now it won't mount and Disk Utility firstaid won't help.

I have an external enclosure containing two SATA drives I also have a "toaster" for dropping in other drives I have on my shelf. In the enclosure I have volumes "Drone Raw" and "Masters" - both mounted.

I pulled an older drive off the shelf also called "Masters" and dropped into the toaster. It mounted fine and I had two "Masters". I've done this before without incident.

Then something went awry and I am not exactly sure of the sequence. I think I unmounted the "Masters" in the enclosure. Maybe both. I can't be sure how I got here. But suddenly the Masters in the enclosure would not mount up at all.

When I used Disk Utility, it thinks that the volume name is now "Drone Raw" and it won't mount. The true "Drone Raw" mounts fine. If I try to mount Masters, it then shows two Drone Raw with one of them being unmounted.

The results of a First aid read:

"Repairing file system.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_hfs -fy -x /dev/rdisk6s2
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Checking extents overflow file.
Checking catalog file.
Invalid sibling link
Rebuilding catalog B-tree.
The volume Drone Raw could not be repaired.
File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed.

Operation failed…"

I tried command line fsck_hfs -r and -f to no avail.

Is this drive hopelessly scrozzed? If so, more academically, why did this happen? I really wasn't doing anything creative or risky at the time.

Thanks for any help

Bill

Comment: For HFS drives, I would be running straight towards [DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) for anything like this. It's really the best tool for the job - it will also let you see what it thinks is the "fix" before committing to it, so should be safe even if it doesn't succeed.

Comment: Thank you. Are you affiliated with the vendor?

Comment: not in the slightest. You have to declare if you are, on Stack Exchange - but not if you're not ;-)